# Setting a "related" route as active in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have two routes in my Aurelia app, a list (Work) and a detail (WorkDetail).

In the navigation, I only have the list route:

```
Home  |  *Work*  |  Contact  |  . . .
```

When I navigate to the WorkDetail view, I would like to set the Work route as active in the navigation.

What I've tried so far is setting the route active in the `activate()` callback of the `WorkDetail` view and inactive on `deactivate()`:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router)
export class WorkDetail {
    constructor(router) {
        this.workRoute = router.routes[2].navModel;
    };

    activate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction) {
        this.workRoute.isActive = true;
    };

    deactivate() {
        this.workRoute.isActive = false;
    };
}
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that on the first activation, the "Work" nav item isn't displayed as "active". If I nav to another WorkItem, it will be set as "active".

Why is that nav item only set as active on a subsequent nav action? or, is there a better way to set a parent/related navigation item as "active"?

Here's my app.js if you're interested: https://gist.github.com/alsoicode/37c5699f29c7562d2bf5

Comment: sounds related to your multiple activate issue.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis I created my project via the Yeoman generator. Should I try starting a new bare-bones project? I'm not sure how to go about debugging this. Ideas? Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Are these two separate routes or are you using a child router / nested resources?

Comment: @PWKad They are two separate routes in the `app.js` file.

Comment: @PWKad I added a link to my app.js so you can see the route definitions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a "Work" link in your nav-bar, which launches the list of "work".  Then when you click on an item in your work list you want the "Work" link in the nav-bar to remain active when the work "detail" screen is activated.

Here's the approach that I used in [this application](http://jdanyow.github.io/aurelia-breeze-northwind/):

In app.js, configure the "work" route:

```js
export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.map([
      { route: '', redirect: 'work' },
      { route: 'work', moduleId: './work/work-section', nav: true, title: 'Work' },
      // ... routes for other top-level sections ...
    ]);
    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

Then add a "work" folder to your project.  This folder will contain the "work" related views and view-models.

In the work folder, add "work-section.js":

```js
/**
* The shell for the work section of the application.  Will display either
* the work-list or work-detail page.
*/
export class WorkSection {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.map([
      { route: '',    moduleId: './work-list',   nav: false, title: '' },
      { route: ':id', moduleId: './work-detail', nav: false, title: '' },
    ]);
  }
}
```

Next add "work-section.html".  It's just a `<router-view>`:

```html
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

Finally, add your `work-list.js` + `.html` and `work-detail.js` + `.html` to the "work" folder.  When clicking on the "work" link in the nav-bar, the work-list will be displayed by default.  When you drill into an item in the work-list, the "work" link in the nav-bar will remain active.

Check out the [sample application](http://jdanyow.github.io/aurelia-breeze-northwind/).  It has three top-level sections (orders, customers and employees).  Each section uses this approach.  The code is [here](https://github.com/jdanyow/aurelia-breeze-northwind/).

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'll get this implemented and see how it behaves.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much. Heading over to your sample application for more examples.