# How can I generate correct detail url using aurelia router?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

One of my application's view-models resides under the routes:

```
http://localhost:9000/#/historical-orders/
http://localhost:9000/#/historical-orders/page/2/
http://localhost:9000/#/historical-orders/page/3/
```

and so on. It's a `list view-model`, so whenever user clicks on one of it's rows, he or she should be directed to:

```
http://localhost:9000/#/historical-orders/details/:orderId
```

Seems simple enough, right? However there's a problem with route generation. Namely: if I'm browsing through one of the pages (urls ending with `page/:pageNumber/`, then calling `router.generate` gives me details url that looks like that: `#/historical-orders/page/1/details/:orderId` which is obviously incorrect. My route config:

```
export class App {
    configureRouter(config, route) {
        config.map([
            {
                route: ["historical-orders", "historical-orders/page/:pageNumber"],
                moduleId: "orders/historical-orders-section",
                name: "historical-orders-section",
                title: "Historical orders",
                nav: true
            }
        ]);
    }
}
```

Historical orders section:

```
export class HistoricalOrders {
    configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.map([
            { 
                route: "", 
                moduleId: "orders/historical/orders-list", 
                title: "Orders history", 
                nav: false
            }, 
            {
                route: "details/:id",
                moduleId: "orders/historical/order-details",
                name: "historical-orders-details",
                title: "Details",
                nav: false
            },
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the detail-view route generation looks quite ordinarily:

```
this._router.generate("historical-orders-details", { id: order.pk });
```

So how to make the router generate proper urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated URL is not incorrect. You are using a child router, that's why the generated url is `#/historical-orders/page/1/details/:orderId`.

To get an URL, such as `#/historical-orders/details/:orderId`, you should do this:

```
export class App {
    configureRouter(config, route) {
        config.map([
            {
                route: ["historical-orders", "historical-orders/page/:pageNumber"],
                moduleId: "orders/historical-orders-section",
                name: "historical-orders-section",
                title: "Historical orders",
                nav: true
            },
            {
                route: "orders/historical-orders/details/:id",
                moduleId: "orders/historical/order-details",
                name: "historical-orders-details",
                title: "Details",
                nav: false
            }
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then

```
let url = this._router.generate("historical-orders-details", { id: order.pk });
```

**EDIT** To access the current router

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router)
export class HistoricalOrders {

    constructor(router) {
       this.router = router; //this is the same app.js router
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that child router thing in order to be able to mark some menu item as active. If I pull the details url out of my `HistoricalOrders` section class into the `App` class, then how do I preserve that functionality?

Comment: you can inject the router and access the functionality that you want. See my edited answer

Comment: It's so dirty... Right now I'm just checking the `isActive` flag in the view layer and marking appropriate item as active. Everything works automatically because the `details` and `list` views live under one section (as far as routing is concerned). If I was to inject the router into my `details` view-model (because injecting it into `HistoricalOrders` doesn't make much sense), then I would have to manually find appropriate 'parent' route and mark it as an active one. Isn't there a simpler, cleaner solution?

Comment: Wait, I believe I'm misunderstanding your issue.. you could check `isActive` without injecting the router or creating a child router. Could reproduce your issue here https://gist.run/?id=8b6395f87f379f0a64e84fe0dc25bbd3 ? Then I'll be able to understand

Comment: I managed to preserve the functionality I was talking about AND generate proper routes for my `DetailViewModel`. I did as you suggested with a small modification to make it all work together - I've copied the `detail` route into the `App` class in order to create proper routes (I had to use `router.parent` for that), but I also left it in the `HistoricalOrders` class because I wanted the `isActive` flag on the 'parent' route to be equal to `true` when navigated to details. You've put me on the right track, so I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: Maybe the answer to this question will clear you understanding of what I was trying to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825847/setting-a-related-route-as-active-in-aurelia .